# WCF HttpsGetUrl A registration already exists for URI

Tags: wcf

This is similar to other Stack postings, but slightly different in that I am only hosting a single wsHttp endpoint (and the mex).  When I leave the httpsGetUrl empty, it shows the server name instead of the public uri that I need (for the wsdl)

Here is the important part of the config.

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehaviors" name="WebApplication1.Service1">
    <clear/>

    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="flatwsdl" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexHttpsBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" listenUriMode="Explicit">         
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint  behaviorConfiguration="flatwsdl" address="wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig"
      contract="WebApplication1.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myServiceBehaviors">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://mydomain.com/integration/Service1.svc" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="flatwsdl">
      <wsdlExtensions />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the public URI, you should use the [`<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.Description.UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior.aspx) behavior in your service behavior, that's exactly what this behavior is for.

```
<behavior name="myServiceBehaviors">
  <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
</behavior>
```

Comment: Solved my issue!