# Generated wsdl uses machine location for ssl - regardless of host headers

Tags: .net, wcf

This seems to be a fairly common problem, but I have been scouring and so far I have not found a solution that works for me.

I have a WCF web service (.svc) running on IIS that works just fine over http. I've set up bindings for http and https. The http binding does NOT use host headers, and it works perfectly. The https binding did not before, but I added them, and it still doesn't work.

The problem is with the soap:address location in the wsdl.

The wsdl from http (correct):

```
<wsdl:service name="UserService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_UserServiceSoap" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_UserServiceSoap">
<soap:address location="http://xxx.net/test_ryan/webservices/xx/UserService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

The wsdl from https (incorrect):

```
<wsdl:service name="UserService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_UserServiceSoap" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_UserServiceSoap">
<soap:address location="http://colo01/test_ryan/webservices/xx/UserService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I do have the ssl certificate working so that when I access xxx.net in a browser I don't get any warnings.

When I try to run services from SoapUI in https, I get a 404 error. The exact same request works fine in the http version.

I have already added the host header to the iis7 https binding (I've tried www.xxx.net and just xxx.net). And run iisreset. And when I verify with

```
cscript.exe /nologo  %systemdrive%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs get /w3svc/1/SecureBindings
```

I see ":443:www.xxx.net"

The service is working over standard http without any "services" or "bindings" elements in the web.config. The behaviors looks like

```
   <behaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />   
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />       
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

I've tried many permutations of the bindings/services, without any luck. Including bindings with security="none" and security="TransportWithMessageCredential". I have also tried setting endpoint address, which has no effect, and serviceMetadata.httpsGetUrl, which prevents the svc/wsdl from loading at all.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF HttpsGetUrl A registration already exists for URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672265/wcf-httpsgeturl-a-registration-already-exists-for-uri)

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I've added useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress but it didn't make a diffence, still getting the local address for the https call. I edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: I just started over with a new IIS web site and created a new certificate, and this solved the problem. Never did figure out what was wrong with the original.